# Is it fair to ask a question that relates to an excerpt of a book?

Tags: discussion

For example, if I'm reading a technical manual and need clarification of a given block of text, can I request that fellow readers and/or the author paraphrase a particular section, or provide missing detail?

Comment: If you manage to make all the examples and citations clear, why not? What do you mean with _"fair"_ BTW? That's not a matter of _fairness_ but if it's an [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question, as usual.

Comment: I can't think of why the source of a question, a book instead of online documentation (or code or whatever), in and of itself would make it off topic.

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ says, it must be an on-topic question, no added restrictions nor extra license. Which among others means it has to be reasonably self-contained. Specifically, your question may not in any way rely on anyone else having your book.

Answer (score 28):

> *"can I request that fellow readers and/or the author paraphrase a particular section, or provide missing detail?"*

Sure you can, as long you provide enough citation (and/or concise and complete code samples) that makes your question self contained.

You **may not** expect anyone to be familiar with the referenced material by just linking to it, or leaving a book's title. This kind of question would be considered being [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's acceptable as long as you clearly state where you are stuck and provide any additional information that illustrates your thought process.  That will give us a good idea **what** to explain.

In my (not so humble) opinion it's not acceptable to post an excerpt with just a request to explain it.